# How take value from prototypes method

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a little problem with prototypes.
I must define a prototype like that :

```
'string'.methodName() => 'string'
```

I tried to do this :

```
String.prototype.methodName = function(){  
    return console.log(this)   
}
```

But this method returns `[String: 'string']`

Can somebody tell me how I can take only value ?

Comment: Whats the usecase??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log()` will print the object, not its value. You can convert it to string with `toString()` method.

```
String.prototype.methodName = function(){  
    return console.log(this.toString())   
}
```